# How to check what type my video card is and its memory size?

Tags: video, ram

I need to install some programs that require minimal size of video card memory, how do I get the size and possibly what vendor and type of my video card?

Output of `lspci  | grep VGA  | cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs lspci -vv -s` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 9981
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
    Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 1800 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this command from a `Terminal`:

```
  lspci  | grep VGA  | cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs lspci -vv -s
```

This will show you a verbose sheet about your video card.

Comment: Which line show video card memory? Please see update.

Comment: Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]

Comment: So my video card is Intel Graphic Family with 256Mb memory? Under windows in dxdiag tool it says my video memory is around 800Mb, which one is correct, I don't want to download gigabytes of program just to let me know that I don't have sufficient video memory.

Comment: Well, this is a little bit tricky. Intel graphics do not have dedicated memory but utilizes some of the computer's system memory. The amount of memory used for graphics may be a fixed amount or may vary up to a maximum amount. It depends on if your computer manufacturer has configured your computer to use a fixed amount, a dynamic amount (varying up to a maximum amount), or a combination of both fixed and dynamic amounts of graphics memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
lspci -v -d '::03xx'
```

Display controllers are assigned to [PIC device class `03`](https://admin.pci-ids.ucw.cz//read/PD/03).